# I am not getting models folder inside src or the react project that I have fetched from figma aws amplify. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, figma, amplifyjs

Problem with aws amplify sync with figma sync, while fetching code to vs code.

I want to know if anyone have solved the problem earlier. Why I am getting this problem ? What step should I undertake inorder to successfully convert the figma design to code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.